# htaccess 301 Redirect to Subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect just the subdirectory pages on a domain to the subdomain. For example, I want:

http://www.example.com/test.htm

To

http://shop.example.com/test.htm

The RedirectMatch I'm using in the htaccess file is:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.example.com/(.*) http://shop.example.com/$1
```

I'm unsure why that is not working?

Comment: `mod_rewrite` should be used, not `mod_alias`, as `RedirectMatch` knows nothing about the domain.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch: _“The supplied regular expression is matched against the **URL-path**”_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^/?test\.htm$ http://shop.example.com/test.htm [R,L]
```

For any URL it will be

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://shop.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

and `/?` allows to use this rule in `.htaccess` or in server's config.

Comment: The `^/?` means `/` is optionally at the beginning. EG: `/test` or `test` will match. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.` should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^shop\.` This way when a user from example.com goes into the directory with the htaccess file, it will check the host, if the host doesn't begin with shop it will redirect them.

Comment: @fyrye If you are explaining it to me - I know it, the request in `.htaccess` is without `/` and in `.conf` - with `/`. `This way when a user from example.com goes into the directory with the htaccess file` I do not think so - he wants to redirect from `www`, may be there are other subdomains using the same folder.

Comment: You explained it as `/?` was a special rule, which is not the case. I provided literal meaning of its usage for the OP to be able to understand it. OP exclaimed wanting to force users within the root domains subdirectory to be redirected to the subdomain. If OP does not have forced `www` in config and host has www as an alias of the root domain, which is very common. Then as I explained in the comment `http://example.com/shop` will fail the `RewriteCond` you provided. At that point I do not assume the OP to have multiple subdomains for the directory as it was not specified.

Comment: Too much water and imagination. You assume, that there is domain without `www` and at the same time assume that there are not other subdomains. If OP will have problems or will add details to his question - everything will be discussed. Otherwise I see no purpose in this dialog.

Comment: Hence my providing the comment and explaining its meaning. Which you perceived to be an attack against your answer as opposed to an alternative solution. The comment is based on my experience with web hosting providers coming standard with www as an alias to the parent domain, to save him from having to ask or add details. There shouldn't have been a dialog or a need for me to defend my comment, as I was trying to help the OP. If I deemed that you were wrong I would have downvoted you or provided my own answer, instead of expand upon your answer to ensure you got acceptance for it.

Answer (score 1):

another easy way

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.example.com/test.htm[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://shop.example.com/test.htm[L,R=301,NC]
```